# Control line breaks in <p> with floated image

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

I have a JS function that writes the code of an HTML form, which is supposed to work in IE7 and above. Part of the (programmatically created) HTML is as follows:

```
<form name="choice" style="text-align:center">
  <p style="display:inline-block;margin-left:24px;margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:0px;margin-right:24px;text-align:left;white-space:nowrap;width:1px">
    <img src="..." style="margin-right:12px">
    Text line number 1<br>
    Text line number 2<br>
    Text line number 3<br>
    Text line number 4<br>
    Text line number 5<br>
    Text line number 6
  </p>

(....some input buttons....)

</form>
```

...where the number and length of the text lines and the size of the image are variable. I'd like to have the contents of the `<p>` left-aligned and centered in the form, so I added `display:inline-block`, `text-align:left` and even `width:1px` to the style of the `<p>` (without the `width:1px` IE7 at least doesn't center the `<p>`, not even adding `margin:0 auto`, which may well be the cause of the trouble).

The problem is that I want the image to appear at the top left of the `<p>`, and the text to start to the right of the image without any line breaks except the explicit `<br>`'s. If I add `float:left` to the style of the image, or if I don't and the first text line is rather long, the text will begin below the image and not to the right of it, which is ugly. If I add `display:inline` I avoid the line break before the start of the text, but there will only be one line of text to the right of the image, and the second line will still be below it, which, if the image has a certain height, is also ugly.

Is there a way to float the image to the left and force the text to occupy the available space to the right of it?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<p>
  <div style="float:left; width:YOUR_WIDTH_1"><img src="" /></div>
  <div style="float:right; width:YOUR_WIDTH_2">
    Text line number 1<br>
    Text line number 2<br>
    Text line number 3<br>
    Text line number 4<br>
    Text line number 5<br>
    Text line number 6
  </div>
</p>
```

If you want you can define the width of the two `div`s. No need to use `inline` or other CSS. It will solve your purpose

EDIT: You need to define the width of the `div`s, to avoid `right div` moving below the `left div`in case your text before the `<br>` grows.

Answer (score 0):

Just float the image left and get rid of all that other stuff you have in there. Look at it on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rf1hbnLy/)

```
#icon {
    float: left;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 0.5em 0.5em 0;
}

<form name="myform" method="POST" action="validate.php">
    <img id="icon" src="icon.png" />
    Text line number 1<br/>
    Text line number 2<br/>
    Text line number 3<br/>
    Text line number 4<br/>
    <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Another [JSFiddle solution](http://jsfiddle.net/2twytaz7/2/) where content is kept out of the form to be more semantically correct.